# Check RPM dependencies

Tags: linux, dependency-management, rpm, rhel

When you are installing a program using `.deb` packages on Ubuntu, you can check dependencies of package using [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com). For example I can see dependencies of Wireshark from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wireshark). As you can see, dependencies marked by red bullet. If you know all packages your program depends them, you can download and install them using `dpkg`.

Is there any alternative website for RPM packages? Specially for RHEL?

I know that I can get these packages' names by other methods such as when installing RPM package using `rpm -i`, but it is not user friendly and needs access to running Linux.

Comment: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/ and https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/ - this is also offtopic (should be in Unix & Linux)

Comment: @marcoms : Your links does not provide dependencies.

Comment: Off topic - belongs on Linux & Unix SE

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In fact that's not a one but four different questions :).

*) First you can quickly list a downloaded package's dependencies/requirements by using the following commands:

```
$ rpm -qp mypackage.rpm --provides
$ rpm -qp mypackage.rpm --requires
```

*) Second, you can use `yum` utility in order to satisfy these (somewhat cryptic) dependencies automatically (assuming that all your repositories are set up correctly, and all the dependencies are available):

```
$ sudo yum install mypackage.rpm
```

*) Third, there are several RPM search resources, some of them already suggested above. I'd like to list another one, just for the reference - [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/).

*) Fourth, there is an additional popular repository for RHEL5 and RHEL6 distros - [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Note that it's not supported by Red Hat.

Hope my answer(s) will help.

Comment: Why use the options `provides` and ` recommends?

Comment: I prefer the short versions `rpm -qPp mypackage.rpm` and `rpm -qRp mypackage.rpm`. Also obviously works for already installed packages (`rpm -qP mypackage` and `rpm -qR mypackage`.)

Answer (score 21):

To merely list all dependencies of a package on the command-line, here is an example which builds upon the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19087701/832230) by Peter:

```
$ PKG="http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6.2-x86_64/pgdg-sl93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm"
```

Using **yum** (recommended):

```
$ yum -q deplist $PKG
package: pgdg-sl93.noarch 9.3-1
  dependency: sl-release
   Unsatisfied dependency
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.1.2-8.el6
  dependency: config(pgdg-sl93) = 9.3-1
   provider: pgdg-sl93.noarch 9.3-1
```

`-q` above is of course optional and is equivalent to `--quiet`.

Using **rpm**:

```
$ rpm -qpR $PKG
/bin/sh  
config(pgdg-sl93) = 9.3-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
sl-release
```

`-qpR` above is equivalent to `--query --package --requires`.

Answer (score 1):

This site http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/ provides a search engine for rpm files. You can see dependencies and description. It also classifies them per distro.